# Ionic 2 : Multiple image load from cache

Tags: android, angularjs, google-chrome, ionic2

I build an Ionic 2 app and I have to display some picture dynamically. To do this I make that :

```
 <ion-menu>
  <ion-content padding>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let guid of groups">
      <ion-card-content>
        <div class="logo-header-order-response">
          <img [src]="this.pdataManager.ptools.dms.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(groups[guid].base64Image)"/>
        </div>
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

But the picture is load a lot of time from the memory cache. I see that in my google chrome console :

[image]

I have two question :

**Can this multiple loading reduce my app performance ?**

**How can I do to have only one loading ?**

Comment: Is the picture online or is it just base64 device based

Comment: Just 64 device based.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an ngFor that is looping the picture load, some more code would be better

Comment: Yes I am ! This code is right my app.html (to exists in my side menu). But I think it not make a difference ?
I will update my code.

Comment: Yes so each image is being loaded for the ngFor

Comment: Sure, but in my case only one image have to be load. (I have only one element in group). But the picture is loaded indefinitly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at this node module [ionic-image-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-image-loader). It helps to do image caching and its what i've been using for my ionic projects. It takes in a simple url and caches it on network access and uses it when there is no network access. 
You can install it using `npm install --save ionic-image-loader`.
And then use th `<img-loader src="https://path.to/my/image.jpg"></img-loader>` tag that caches the image. For images with similar urls, no multiple fetching is done. You can read more from the shared link.

Comment: Thanks but can I use  it with base64 encoded file ?